# why does full-screen display mode using mvim on OSX Yosemitie repeat lines of code?

Tags: vim, osx-yosemite, macvim, vim-plugin

I installed this [vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) on OSX Yosemite (10.10.5) and every time I enter the full-screen mode with mvim I have a problem that occurs when scrolling down and then back up to the top of the file. The display gets stuck on the top-most line and repeats it in the window. It doesn't actually write to the file, but it is enough to make the application unusable. Does anyone know what the cause may be? I don't even know where to start.

Here is an example [image: example] of my display.

Comment: Please phrase the title as your question.

Comment: There isn't enough information to tell what is going on. You also linked to the same picture twice.

Comment: @FDinoff sorry i had been drinking. maybe this is more clear and i have fixed the link issue.

Comment: I don't feel like debugging that gigantic vim configuration. Here are some guideline to debugging a vimrc http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file. Does hitting `<C-l>` make all of the duplicate lines go away?

Comment: ^ That. And if that doesn't work, I believe that full-screen mode in macvim is known to have some bugs and artefacts... So you may want to [report this as a bug](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues) for this.